# Model can't be fixed the orientation

Tags: ros, pose, model

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, ROS community!

I was learning [the tutorial](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=model_population&cat=build_world) about the placing models in some orders and I wanted to implement it in my project. I took some models from 3D google repository and corrected them by following this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aP4sDyrRzpU).

My problem is the model (`white_shelf2`) can't be rotated on 90 degrees. I tried differently to fix the numbers of orientation (yaw exactly) in the world file (below it attached), but I cant still understand why the number were not published in Gazebo.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" ?> 
 <sdf version="1.5"> 
 <world name="default">

<include> 
<uri>model://ground_plane</uri> 
</include>

<include> 
<uri>model://sun</uri> 
</include>

<include> 
<uri>model://market_layout</uri> 
<name>market layout</name> 
<pose>0.107915 -0.228911 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00</pose> 
</include>

<include> 
<uri>model://kassa</uri> 
<name>kassa</name> 
<pose>-4.712210 0.153002 -0.000002 0.000003 0.00 -1.573301</pose> 
</include>

<population name="white_shelves_population1"> 
<model name="white_shelf1"> 
<include>   
<static>true</static>   
<uri>model://white_shelves</uri> 
</include> 
</model> 
<pose>0.5 -7.4 0 0 0 0</pose> <!--pose of all shelves together -->  
<box>
<size>14 0.5 3</size> <!-- <size> is size of all shelves; all shelves will be in the size together -->
</box> 
<model_count>14</model_count> 
<distribution> 
<type>linear-x</type> <!-- models place along x-axis --> 
</distribution> 
</population>

<population name="white_shelves_population2"> 
<model name="white_shelf2"> 
<include> 
<static>true</static> 
<uri>model://white_shelves</uri> 
</include> 
</model> 
<pose>7.313923 1.442630 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.623000</pose> 
<box> 
<size>0.5 1.0 3.0</size> 
</box> 
<model_count>1</model_count> 
<distribution> 
<type>linear-y</type> 
</distribution> 
</population>
</world> 
</sdf>
```

This is screenshots:

[image: image description]

[image: image description]

In GUI, I placed the model in right position for getting the pose coordinates. Because, the "save" function doesn't work there, so I fixed the coordinates in my world file.

Jade, Ubuntu 14.04, Gazebo 5.1.0

Thank you in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/229587/model-can%27t-be-fixed-the-orientation/) by [dyupleks](https://answers.ros.org/users/22089/dyupleks/) on ROS Answers with karma: 200 on 2016-03-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The problem was decided in Gazebo answers. The link is [here](http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/12884/model-cant-be-fixed-the-orientation/).

In case, I duplicate my question in Gazebo and ROS answers, Do I destroy the community rules?

---

Originally posted by [dyupleks](https://answers.ros.org/users/22089/dyupleks/) with karma: 200 on 2016-03-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0